# Eclipse set up for multiple languages

Tags: eclipse, installation, workspace

I have been using the Eclipse platform for Java, javaEE, c++, python and PHP - in various school projects. Now that I am a bit more comfortable with it I would like to have some more accurate instructions on how to set it up. I am on windows7 - I had dropped the eclipse itself in my Dropbox and created workspaces as needed but this ended up in a chaos of settings spread here and there and in various bugs (which showed up when I tried to update to Juno - now features like [templates are broken](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385665)).

So what is the recommended way of setting eclipse up for various languages ? Should I 
download the latest release, add the plugins I need (cdt, pdt etc) and then create different workspaces for the different languages (like eclipse_python, eclipse_java, eclipse_javaEE, etc )? How do you set Eclipse up ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been using eclipse intensively for about 6 years now, and I'd recommend setting up a separate eclipse installation for up to 1 or 2 different programming languages. The reason is that with too many plug-ins, eclipse might consume too much memory or processor time (of course, depending on what the plug-ins do in background and so on...) which may lead to an unresponsive UI.

I also recommend using separate workspaces for each eclipse installation so that the different configurations/installations don't interfere with each other.

I wrote a little command line script which allows me to switch the .metadata directory in a workspace for use with a portable drive (supports two modes: home and portable) maybe someone finds that useful...

```
@ECHO OFF

REM This Script is used to ease using eclipse in a portable manner
REM The script allows to easily switch between several workspace metadata

REM arg1: eclipse runnable
REM arg2: workspace dir
REM arg3: metadata mode (portable or home)

:CHECK_ARG_ONE
IF %1 == "" GOTO :HELP
IF /i %1 == "/h" GOTO :HELP
IF /i %1 == "/?" GOTO :HELP
IF /i %1 == "/help" GOTO :HELP
IF /i %1 == "-h" GOTO :HELP
IF /i %1 == "-?" GOTO :HELP
IF /i %1 == "-help" GOTO :HELP
IF /i %1 == "--h" GOTO :HELP
IF /i %1 == "--?" GOTO :HELP
IF /i %1 == "--help" GOTO :HELP


:CHECK_ARG_TWO
IF %2 == "" GOTO :ERROR_ARG_TWO


:CHECK_ARG_THREE
IF %3 == "" GOTO :ERROR_ARG_THREE


:PREPARE
SET "ECLIPSE_RUNNABLE=%1"
SET "WORKSPACE_DIR=%2"
ECHO Working Dir: %CD%
ECHO Eclipse Runnable: %ECLIPSE_RUNNABLE%
ECHO Workspace Dir: %WORKSPACE_DIR%
SET "MD=.metadata"
SET "MD_HOME=.metadata_home"
SET "MD_PORTABLE=.metadata_portable"
PUSHD %WORKSPACE_DIR%
IF /i %3 == home GOTO :HOME
IF /i %3 == portable GOTO :PORTABLE
GOTO :ERROR_ARG_THREE_WRONG


:HOME
ECHO Starting home version
IF EXIST %MD% (
    IF EXIST %MD_HOME% (
        IF EXIST %MD_PORTABLE% (
            GOTO :ERROR_MD_PORTABLE_EXISTS_ALREADY
        ) ELSE (
            REN %MD% %MD_PORTABLE%
            REN %MD_HOME% %MD%
        )
    )
) ELSE (
    IF NOT EXIST %MD_HOME% (
        GOTO :ERROR_MD_HOME_EXISTS_NOT
    ) ELSE (
        REN %MD_HOME% %MD%
    )
)
GOTO :RUN


:PORTABLE
ECHO Starting portable version
IF EXIST "%MD%" (
    IF EXIST "%MD_PORTABLE%" (
        IF EXIST "%MD_HOME%" (
            GOTO :ERROR_MD_HOME_EXISTS_ALREADY
        ) ELSE (
            REN "%MD%" %MD_HOME%
            REN "%MD_PORTABLE%" %MD%
        )
    )
) ELSE (
    IF NOT EXIST "%MD_PORTABLE%" (
        GOTO :ERROR_MD_PORTABLE_EXISTS_NOT
    ) ELSE (
        REN "%MD_PORTABLE%" %MD%
    )
)
GOTO :RUN


:ERROR_ARG_TWO
ECHO No second argument supplied (workspace dir)
GOTO :END_ERROR


:ERROR_ARG_THREE
ECHO No third argument supplied (metadata mode - home ^| portable)
GOTO :END_ERROR


:ERROR_ARG_THREE_WRONG
ECHO Supplied third argument (metadata mode) must match (home ^| portable)
GOTO :HELP


:ERROR_MD_HOME_EXISTS_ALREADY
ECHO Trying to rename "%MD%", but the metadata directory "%MD_HOME%" already exists!
GOTO :END_ERROR


:ERROR_MD_HOME_EXISTS_NOT
ECHO Neither "%MD%" nor "%MD_HOME%" exist!
GOTO :END_ERROR


:ERROR_MD_PORTABLE_EXISTS_ALREADY
ECHO Trying to rename "%MD%", but the metadata directory "%MD_PORTABLE%" already exists!
GOTO :END_ERROR


:ERROR_MD_PORTABLE_EXISTS_NOT
ECHO Neither "%MD%" nor "%MD_PORTABLE%" exist!
GOTO :END_ERROR


:HELP
ECHO.
ECHO Eclipse starter script to switch between home and portable metadata
ECHO ©Till Kolditz 2011 (till.kolditz@googlemail.com)
ECHO.
ECHO This Script is used to ease using eclipse in a portable manner.
ECHO It allows to easily switch between portable and "home" or stationary
ECHO workspace metadata.
ECHO.
ECHO Usage: run.bat (eclipse_runnable) (workspace_dir) (home ^| portable)
ECHO.
ECHO Example1: run.bat eclipse\eclipse.exe workspace home
ECHO Example2: run.bat "eclipse (x64)\eclipse.exe" workspace_special portable
GOTO :END


:RUN
POPD
START "Eclipse" %ECLIPSE_RUNNABLE% -data %WORKSPACE_DIR%
GOTO :END


:END_ERROR
POPD
REM PAUSE for debugging
PAUSE
GOTO :END


:END
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: So you mean it is better to download say eclipse cdt and eclipse javaee etc in separate dirs and fire up the one needed ? Also your script is used to run those various eclipse installs with different metadata folders (so different workspaces) ? I am not sure I get where the portable and home distinction comes in

Comment: 1) yes
2) I made this script because I have my development tools (eclipses) on an SSD and take it to the university everyday - the drive letters cannot be the same like when I have the SSD plugged in at home. Consequently, any absolute paths (e.g. for build path variables) change every time I use the SSD as a portable drive. My trick is to have 2 different metadata folders and pick the appropriate one each time. Therefor, create your workspace once with all necessary settings set. Then copy the whole .metadata folder and name it ".metadata_portable".

Comment: Ok - I'll be away maybe so I may not respond promptly - you then have to sync your metadata and metadata_portable - or not ?

Comment: I hadn't thought about that when writing the script. Using my script you'll have to make changes (which result in changed metadata) in the portable or home version again, respectively.
But you could create a third metadata folder (e.g. .metadata_base) and create hard links inside the other two metadata folders (home/portable) into this base folder for any settings you want to be the same for both home/portable