# how to configure eclipse to support java?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I was using eclipse for coding with C/C++, now my eclipse shows "C/C++ Eclipse platform".

I want to configure it to support java, j2ee, but I'm at a loss on how to do.
I'm using fedora. Related info about my eclipse is:

```
Eclipse Platform

Version: 3.7.1
Build id: R3_7_1

(c) Copyright Eclipse contributors and others 2000, 2011.  All rights reserved.
Visit http://www.eclipse.org/platform

This product includes software developed by the
Apache Software Foundation http://www.apache.org/
```

Comment: You can download a separate bundle of eclipse for java-related stuff.

Comment: They can coexist on the same system? so if I open eclipse, which one will show ?

Comment: @user1944267 well they can. But it is easier to have separated installations for Java and C++. Especially when you start adding some language specific plugins.

Comment: I found another post "kind of" similar. the question is a bit different, but the guy that answers it goes in depth about having more than one eclipse with other languages. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709683/eclipse-set-up-for-multiple-languages

Answer (score 2):

Click, "Help" > "Install New Software". Work with "All Available Sites", select "Eclipse Java Development Tools" and then click "Finish".

Once installed, you will have additional "perspectives" and "project types" available. Try "Window" > "Open Perspective" > "Java", and then "File" > "New" > "Java Project".

Answer (score 0):

Start by

1. installing java VM (open jdk or JDK)
2. Help > Install New Software >All Available Sites then choose "Eclipse Java Development Tools" and then click "Finish"
3. Help > EclipseMarketplace to add all necessary plugin according to what exactly you want to do with Java(Standard, EE, GUI...)

Comment: Will the Coexistence of java and c/c++ on the same Eclipse cause problems? Compared to installing a new java based eclipse, which is better? thanks!

Comment: @user1944267 No. Not all sofar i know, just pay attention to use the right VM